# URI.parse documentation

Tags: ruby, uri

In [the documentation for `URI.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse) is the following code:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.ruby-lang.org/")
p uri
# => #<URI::HTTP:0x202281be URL:http://www.ruby-lang.org/>
```

I'm wondering why, in the example, there is the letter `p`, e.g. `p uri`.

Also, how is using `.parse` different from doing `uri = URI("http://...")`, as in the example at the top of the page?

Comment: `p` is just used to output the content of the variable `uri`. It doesn't have anything to do with the `URI` library itself.

Comment: I voted to close, but your second question is valid. Sorry. It seems `uri = URI("http://...")` and `uri = URI.parse("http://...")` do the same. I am not sure, because the documentation is not clear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `URI(url)` and `URI.parse(url)` do exactly the same:

```
u1 = URI("http://stackoverflow.com/")
u2 = URI.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/")
u1 == u2 # => true
```

Comment: `URI.parse` is a lot more clear as to what's going on. That crazy short-hand notation of having a *method* with exactly the same name as the *class* is confusing if not obnoxious.

Comment: @tadman, thanks for your comment. I was wondering how `URI(url)` worked. I agree that `URI.parse` is a lot more clear.